# Animation style was overridden

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml

I was making animation for all my TreeView.....

Having a app.xaml with:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeView}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TreeViewItem.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                             From="0" To="1" BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:01" FillBehavior="Stop"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
      </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

It works for for every TreeView, I can see the TreeViewItem fading in.

But then if the TreeView is defined as below with Triggers in the style:

```
   <TreeView>
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
                          //Do some work
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.Resources>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Item1">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Item2">
                <TreeViewItem Header="Item3"/>
                <TreeViewItem Header="Item4"/>
            </TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Item5"/>
        </TreeViewItem>            
        <TreeViewItem Header="Item6"/>
    </TreeView>
```

The animation will not be working anymore.
Is there any solution or workaround for this?  I don't really want to put the whole animation code inside the TreeView...

Comment: You are overriding your animation style with the one that defines the trigger. The way how styles are resolved is like any other WPF resource: it will walk up the logical tree until it finds one and stops. In your case it will find the style with the trigger and will not continue further. Phil solution is the correct one, inherit your trigger style from the animation style using BasedOn.

Comment: @Claudiu oh, so there is no solution that I can say apply the animation style to any tree, no matter what they define for trigger?  Because I am trying to find a away that I can apply them globally without changing the code on the TreeView.

Comment: I am afraid not. If you don't set the style manually it will be set to the first one find in the treeView resource (including inherited resources). You are applying the Trigger style anyway (placing it in the treeView resource dictionary) so just go ahead and derive your trigger style from the animation style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) create a base named style, with your existing style

```
<Style x:Key="baseTreeViewStyle" 
       TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}"> existing style here </Style>
```

2) create a style without a name based on your base style - this will be your implicit global style

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" 
       BasedOn={StaticResource baseTreeViewStyle} />
```

3) extend the base style in your tree view

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" 
       BasedOn="{StaticResource baseTreeViewStyle}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
              //Do some work
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Now you get an implicit global style, but if you need specific additional behaviour you override the base style.

To be even more thorough your base style should be based on the default TreeViewItem style

```
<Style x:Key="baseTreeViewStyle" 
       TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" 
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TreeViewItem}}"> 
           existing style here 
</Style>
```

Comment: But in this solution, that's mean I have to go to every `TreeView` that has trigger in their style and extends their style base on the animation style?  There is no solution that I can apply the animation no matter what they define in the TreeView style?  Or make it globally to say all `TreeViewItem` style will be `BaseOn` what I define in App.xaml?

Comment: An alternative is to define several 'base' treeview styles - as many as you require - then specify style={} on every tree view.  Or in every scope create a keyless style based on the base style of choice which will then affect all treeviews in that scope.